# Creating trigger to prevent insert with condition from other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

im trying to create trigger that prevent insert on buku_dalam_pinjam with certain condition from other table which is anggota_dosen. this is my current trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `buku_dalam_pinjam_BI`
BEFORE INSERT ON `buku_dalam_pinjam`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if (buku_dalam_pinjam.id_agt_dosen=anggota_dosen.id_agt_dosen and 
        anggota_dosen.ttl_proses_pinjam >=5) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text="error message";

    end if;
END
```

it was succesfully created, then when i try to insert data on buku_dalam_pinjam
it gave me error message, but when i erase the trigger it let me insert on buku_dalam_pinjam table. so is there any mistake in my trigger?

[anggota_dosen table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0XST.png)

[buku_dalam_pinjam table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb0E0.png)

[error message when i include the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhPO.png)

Comment: Are you saying the mysql is wrong in throwing this message? Can you prove it?

Comment: no i mean i cant insert on buku_dalam_pinjam table even when the condition is not met

Comment: I'm baffled the error is clear no such table exists , creating a trigger on buku_dalam_pinjam does not create such a table. In fact I don't see the relevance of the trigger code to the question.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i fixed my last question i hope it can be understandable

Comment: The trigger is nonsense. I suspect you need new.buku_dalam_pinjam.id_agt_dosen instead of buku_dalam_pinjam.id_agt_dosen AND you aren't selecting anggota_dosen at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
drop trigger if exists buku_dalam_pinjam_BI;
delimiter $$
CREATE  TRIGGER `buku_dalam_pinjam_BI`
BEFORE INSERT ON buku_dalam_pinjam
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if exists (select 1 from anggota_dosen 
            where new.id_agt_dosen = anggota_dosen.id_agt_dosen and 
        anggota_dosen.ttl_proses_pinjam >=5) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text="error message";

    end if;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: thank you sir, its now work like its intended :) . may i know what '1' mean in 'select 1 from anggota_dosen?

Comment: 'If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE.' .. 'Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html